# Preventing the dismissal of a view controller in a segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am using StoryBoards and am trying to overlay a View Controller's view on top of another View Controller's view so that the two are visible (the top one has a couple of transparent areas).

If I connect the two together with a modal Segue and then call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTutorial" sender:nil];` the source view is removed and the destination one is shown. No joy.

If I connect them with a push Segue, calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTutorial" sender:nil];` doesn't bring up the new view. Embedding the source view controller in a Navigation Controller brings up the destination view, but also removes the source view. No joy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of using a segue, just load the view and add it as a subview?

Comment: Eric, I guess you could do that using a CONTAINER VIEW that sits on top.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884   it works!

Answer (score 3):

@Inafziger: I thought I would have been able to do that with a segue, but segues are not the way. Also, as I wanted to keep working with the Storyboard and avoid making a new nib file from scratch, here's what I did:

`tutorialView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tutorial"];`

`[self.view addSubview:tutorialView.view];`

Then in the Storyboard, write "Tutorial" in the ViewController's Identifier field.