# Xcode Add Child To Container View

Tags: ios, xcode, containers, parent

Sorry if the answer to this is obvious - its not to me and I can't seem to find a straight forward answer by searching.

I've created a Container View Controller which as default comes with a child. 
I want to add a second (and third) child in the storyboard but I can see how to link up a new View Controller with the Container View Controller.

Can anyone advise?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it's one of those bizarre things about iOS ...

it's like the most normal, common thing you need to do ------- but you can't find it explained anywhere!

Here's the full story ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

Scroll to the section: **"Advanced! How to change the type of container view."** which is what you ask!  Cheers.