# what is the difference between view and container view in iOS design?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview

I was trying my hand at Xcode lately and i came across the view and the container view.
I was not able to figure out the difference.
Can anybody explain it to me.

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355022/what-is-container-view-in-ios-5-sdk) about container view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIView object claims a rectangular region of its enclosing superview (its parent in the view hierarchy) and is responsible for all drawing in that region ...

Container View defines a region within a view controller's view subgraph that can include a child view controller.

Comment: The answer on this link is a little more detailed: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859824/uiview-vs-container-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859824/uiview-vs-container-view)