# Custom segue, but leave the previous scene showing

Tags: objective-c, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Imagine a custom segue ...

```
-(void)perform
    {
    UIView *sv = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
    UIView *dv = ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view;

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    [window insertSubview:dv aboveSubview:sv];

    [dv coverFromRight:0 then:^
        {
        [self.sourceViewController
         presentViewController:self.destinationViewController
         animated:NO completion:nil];
        }];
    }
```

Which in fact, only PARTIALLY (!) covers the "underneath, previous" scene,

and in fact DOES NOT call "presentViewController", so, the "underneath, previous" scene in fact keeps operating normally.

```
-(void)perform
    {
    UIView *sv = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
    UIView *dv = ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view;

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    [window insertSubview:dv aboveSubview:sv];

    [dv coverButOnlyHalfWay:0 then:^
        {
        }];
    }
```

Essentially, is this possible?

In fact, I've found from experiment the above works (!!).  BUT when you come to the custom unwind segue, it does not work: everything crashes.  (Perhaps as you'd expect.)

What's the situation?  is there a way to make a custom segue, which, covers only say half the "original, underneath" scene and leaves that scene running?

(I appreciate you can just implement this using a container view, but it's not as clean as a whole segue scene.)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a segue? You can just add your view as a subview and position it correct using CGRectMake, this would be much easier.

// Size Your View with X, Y coordinates

```
[viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 192)];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:viewController];
```

Comment: Hi Justin!  For sure as I mention at the end there, you could use a container view .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884 (or indeed just roll in a view, as you say).  But life is much, much easier, for your logic, data handling, and so on, when you have a whole new VC.  (After all, whenever you pop on a whole new scene .. you could just use a UIView!)  So yeah I wonder if you can have a "partial screen" segue like that...

Comment: I am not talking about a container view, I am saying just add the view to your current view. You can still use a view controller to contain your logic (I have used this approach to create tabs in an app) The segue only helps in move from one scene to another.

Comment: Hi Justin.  Yes, I've sure done that a few times! Note that, any time you use a segue - you could just do that!!  life is much easier using scenes and segues (much much easier to compartmentalise and so on), so I'm wondering if it's possible.  Note that using a container view, is, the totally natural way to do what you say these days, I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884