# iOS Storyboards: How to segue to the second view with a back button to the first view, but without displaying the first view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Here is my storyboard configuration:

Navigation Controller -> View Controller A -> Push-> View Controller B
^
| 
Modal
^
|
View Controller C

What I want to achieve: When a button is pressed in View C, directly View B will be opened modally (No part of View A is to be displayed). Also, View B will have a navigation back button to View A.

To achieve this,

- I set up the illustrated storyboard.
- I created a segue between View C and the Navigation Controller of View A/B.
- In the 'prepareForSegue' method of View Controller C, I get an instance of View Controller A as the first element in the navigation. In this instance, I set a variable like 'directlyProceedToViewB=YES'.
- In the viewDidLoad method of View Controller A, I check the variable 'directlyProceedToViewB' and if it is YES, I call 'performSegueWithIdentifier' to segue to View B

The result is so that, first View A is opened modally and after displaying it a very short time, View B is opened with a push animation (View B can navigate back to View A, which is good). But I do not want View A to be displayed any time at all. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

To better visualize, I'm adding a screenshot with more example cases to support:

[image]

Here are some cases I want to support:

- We can start with ViewC, click on 'Modally Display B' which opens ViewB, then click 'Back to A' to navigate back to ViewA, then click on 'Dismiss Modal' on ViewA to go back to ViewC
- We can start with ViewD, clcik on 'Modally Display A' which opens ViewA, then click on 'PushB' to open ViewB, then go back and forth between A and B and modally dismiss to ViewD.

Comment: Rather to perform segue from viewA to viewB. Simply have a segue between viewC and viewB. Also you could set no to animation.

Comment: But in that case, I wouldn't have a back navigation from viewB to ViewA, would I?

Comment: It would be almost impossible to help unless you please INCLUDE AN IMAGE of your storyboard, showing your goal.

Comment: It's possible you need t simply use container views for this.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

Comment: create a segue between View C and View B and on a button click in C call method performseguewithIdentifier why are you complicating this so much???

Comment: @Rohit Then once the View B is opened, how will I be able to navigate back to View A?

Comment: @aligurbuz it would work normally as stack will have your recent on top(viewB) and previous at bottom(viewA) ,and for viewC it's just present and dismiss. If user jumps directly to viewC and then to viewB in that case it might not show viewA. Still you could try this out.

Comment: @walle84 I have edited and added example scenarios and yes, the user can start from ViewC. In that case, performing segue from C to B does not allow to navigate back from B to A.

Comment: @JoeBlow I have added images of my storyboard

Comment: @aligurbuz once for navigating back to view A once View B is opened you can create a segue between the both and call them whenever you want to navigate.

Comment: @Rohit I would prefer to avoid it as it would complicate my design. Imagine ViewB like a detail view of ViewA. For example, ViewA is a table view, and ViewB is a view corresponding to clicking on one of the table cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

First, I discovered that, my original proposal of

> In the viewDidLoad method of View Controller A, I check the variable
>   'directlyProceedToViewB' and if it is YES, I call
>   'performSegueWithIdentifier' to segue to View B

works as I desired on iOS 7 but does not work on iOS 8.

So the solution is, in the viewDidLoad method of View Controller A, if 'directlyProceedToViewB' is YES, rather than calling performSegueWithIdentifier, use the following code:

```
ViewControllerB *destVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerBStoryboardID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, some corrections: those are not views but view controllers. And "view A" is not pushed into the `UINavigationController` but it's the root.

After that, I suggest making the segue in "view C" an unwind segue and implement the `IBAction` in "view A" by pushing "view B" with `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:bViewController animated:NO]`.

EDIT (adding some details):

I assume that in `ViewControllerA`'s `viewWillAppear` you present `ViewControllerC` in a not animated manner.
Implement an unwinding action like `(IBAction)unwindAndThenGoToB:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue` in `ViewControllerA`.
In the storyboard connect the button in `ViewControllerC` to the **Exit** icon and select the previously defined method.
Then implement the method with the push call I wrote earlier.
ps: for documentation there is plenty on Apple's website.

Comment: Try to see if it's better now.

Comment: I'm not presenting VC_C from VC_A. That's not path I'm concerned. The paths I want to achieve are: VC_C -> VC_B modally with a possibility to VC_B to VC_A as a back navigation. And after VC_A is opened from VC_B, it may go to VC_B again with normal navigation or modally back VC_C.

Comment: The sources I checked for 'unwind segues' describe it as a back navigation. In this case, my path of VC_C -> VC_A (invisibly) -> VC_B is a forward navigation path. Can the 'unwind segues' still be used?

Answer (score 0):

Implement this using delegates.Decalre protocol in which class you want and define those methods and call the methods in the view controller you want.There is no many ways of calling some view and showing back button to go different view.modal view is just a concept.and you can use delegate methods to call whatever class you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got a way to do so:-

You need to set no animation for segue from viewC to viewA as shown in below image. Then set a segue identifier for segue from viewA to viewB namely, "viewB" and in your viewA .m file add following code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Place your conditional check here.
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewB" sender:self];  //Will directly lead to viewB and viewA won't be shown as no animation is there from viewC to viewA.
}
```

And your rest flow be like-wise.

[image: No animation for transition from viewC to viewB]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't create the effect I want either. I tried it and it still displayed ViewA for a short time before navigating to ViewB, but this time opening ViewA without animation. I want to keep the modal transition animation. But it will look like it is modally opening ViewB from ViewC directly, without displaying any part of ViewA.

Comment: For that you need to modallypresent viewB and not viewA but in that case you won't have viewA in stack for back functionality. So you need to re-think about your app flow.