# Changing UILabel's text only works inside viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit, uilabel

I'm trying to make a function that I can call on to update my UILabel's `scoreLabel.text`. However, I get an error whenever I try to change it. What's confusing to me is that I don't receive an error when changing it inside `viewDidLoad()`. Everywhere else returns the following error:

[image: Imgur Link]

In the console I also get error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

So what I've been lead to believe is that when calling my function to update the text, the view hasn't loaded the UILabel yet. But I'm certain that this function is called only once the view *has* loaded.

Things I've checked/tried for:

- That my IBOutlet is properly connected
- That my function is being called
- Using both `scoreLabel.text` and `self.scoreLabel.text`
- Using a Strong and Weak outlet connection

I am also positive that `changeTextLabel` is being called after `scoreLabel` is loaded into memory. But again my error seems to say otherwise.

Here's a complete markup of my code. I've removed some irrelevant details for readability:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //This is where all my other code was
    print(scoreLabel.text)
    scoreLabel.text = "Testing" //This line can be run
}

func changeTextLabel() {
    print("changeTextLabel called")
    if self.scoreLabel != nil {
        self.scoreLabel.text = "yay"
    } else {
        print("scoreLabel is nil") //This is called every time
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your time

**Edit:**`GameScene.swift`

This is only the part that should be of concern

```
func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile: SKSpriteNode, monster: SKSpriteNode) {
    print("Hit")
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let object = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController") as! GameViewController

    object.changeTextLabel()
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: have you tried to print the `self.scoreLabel` to check if its nil or not?

Comment: where are you calling `changeTextLabel` method from some other controller?

Comment: Check with breakpoints wether viewdidload is called first or changetextlabel is called first.

Comment: is it necessary to call `self` on the variable in your `func`?

Comment: @Tj3n Yes, the value is nil when called from `changeLabelText()` but from called from `viewDidLoad()` the value is `Testing` and is a normal string

Comment: Where you calling your changeTextLabel() from...It should work if you calling from viewWillAppears...

Comment: @Joe I'm calling it from another file, GameScene.swift, after it detects a collision of two Sprite. I know this function is called after the view is loaded.

Comment: What is the value of `scoreLabel` before crash occur?

Comment: @NiravD viewDidLoad is called first

Comment: can you show  GameScene.swift code?

Comment: @ZaidPathan Assuming you mean scoreLabel.text, and it's value is "Testing" although my function changeTextLabel seems to think it is nil

Comment: @Mathperson , I don't mean `scoreLabel.text`, I mean `scoreLabel` only.

Comment: it could be problem with your segue method way you passing data or score could be nil..

Comment: @Sahil Edited my post

Comment: let game = GameViewController() //where is instantation...you need to instantiate view controller..and then you will get proper reference to your GameViewController

Comment: @ZaidPathan `<UILabel: 0x7f9eb66074b0; frame = (0 0; 1000 1000); text = 'what'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x600000099910>>` When printed from viewDidLoad

Comment: you can't access another class IBOulet using this

Comment: @Mathperson , please print it exact before crash, and let me know

Comment: @ZaidPathan Just trying to print it's value crashes it when done from changeLabelText

Comment: @Sahil That's why I'm having `GameScene.swift` call `changeLabelText()` from `GameViewController` so It can access it

Comment: check my answer :)

Comment: @Mathperson Check my answer once

Comment: 6 answers! Are you Ethan Hawke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont fully know your project setup but your approach seems complicated, its not what you should do in SpriteKit games. So I dont think its a good idea to tell you how to fix your current problem.

You should create your UI, such as labels, buttons etc using SpriteKit APIs (SKLabelNodes, SKSpriteNodes, SKNodes etc) directly in the relevant SKScene(s).

Your GameViewController should only really handle presenting SKScenes. so there should be next to no code there apart from loading the 1st SKScene.

If you have multiple SKScenes (MenuScene, ShopScene, SettingScene etc) your approach will fall apart because the score label will show in all SKScenes. GameViewController presents all your SKScenes, so whats added to GameViewController shows in all SKscenes. That means you have to remove/add labels and other UI for each scene and it will be chaos.

So to create a score label you should do this directly in the relevant scene. I like to use the lazy var approach to keep the setup code for the label in the same spot.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

      lazy var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode = {
          let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "HelveticaNeue")
          label.text = "SomeText"
          label.fontSize = 22
          label.fontColor = .yellow
          label.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
          return label
      }()

      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

          addChild(scoreLabel)
      }
}
```

Than you can update it like this directly in the collision code you have.

```
scoreLabel.text = "NewText"
```

Now when you change from 1 SKScene to another SKScene you dont have to worry about removing this label, SpriteKit will do it for you.

You could also use xCodes level editor to add this label visually, similar to storyboards. This brings me to my final suggestion, which is that storyboards are not really used in SpriteKit games. Storyboards are for ViewControllers and in SpriteKit you are working with SKScenes.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line,

```
 let game = GameViewController()
 game.changeTextLabel()
```

You should create GameViewController object using XIB or Storyboard.

In your case it is just creating object using .swift file, formally class.
You should create your object using View which is having IBOutlet connection with `scoreLabel`.

Try (If using **Storyboard**),

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
let gameVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController") as! UIViewController
```

or (If using **XIB**)

```
var gameVC = GameViewController(nibName: "GameViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Update you `changeTextLabel` with following ([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29322364/3411787)),

```
func changeTextLabel() {
    print(self.view)
    print("changeTextLabel called")
    if self.scoreLabel != nil {
        self.scoreLabel.text = "yay"
    } else {
        print("scoreLabel is nil") //This is called every time
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my GameScene to use this now, very helpful to know I've been doing it wrong! However, it hasn't fixed my error. And scoreLabel.text still = nil

Comment: @Mathperson Please update your question what changes you did, so I can look closer we are on right track.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are not getting memory of label in any other function.It happens because of so many reasons.

One reason could be @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
 Try to create a strong variable outlet.

```
@IBOutlet strong var scoreLabel: UILabel!
```

Second reason could be that you are calling changeTextLabel before the label gets memory. So call it later.

Comment: I've tried both using a strong and weak variable outlet, and changeTextLabel is being for sure called after the label is initialized into memory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It should be working for you as well. It is working for me.

Comment: one more thing add a breakpoint and check if label is nil then do this self.scoreLabel?.text = "yay"

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
self.scoreLabel.text = "yay"
```

With

```
self.scoreLabel?.text = "yay"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes and try again:

```
   func changeTextLabel() {
        print("changeTextLabel called")
        if self.scoreLabel != nil {
           self.scoreLabel.text = "yay"
        }

   }


func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile: SKSpriteNode, monster: SKSpriteNode) {
    print("Hit")
    let game =  STORYBOARD.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("STORYBOARD_IDENTIFIER") as! GameViewController
    game.changeTextLabel()
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: Updated my GameScene to use this now, very helpful to know I've been doing it wrong! However, it hasn't fixed my error. And scoreLabel.text still = nil

Comment: The label has not come into memory unless the view is loaded you need to load the view before using the label . In this case you create instance of Game View Controller but its view has not been loaded ie the label is still nil. If you present the viewcontroller or pushviewcontroller that will resolve your issue .

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "present" the viewcontroller?

Comment: can you post the class where you are using projectileDidCollideWithMonster delegate?