# Objects of presenting/showing ViewController equal to nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, presentviewcontroller

This func is used for showing/presenting ViewController.

```
let noteViewController = NoteViewController()

extension NoteTableViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
func remindLater() {
    if let note = notificationNote?.copy() as? Note {
        noteViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        noteViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        noteViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
        resultSearchController.searchBar.isHidden = true
        present(noteViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //show(noteViewController, sender: self)
    }
}
}
```

On the ViewController i am trying to present i've an outlet for UIDatePicker object. On `viewdidLoad()` method i have this line that causes an error.

```
frameDatePicker = remindDatePicker.frame
```

So, i found remindDatePicker and other objects equal to nil.
Where should i find a mistake?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321383/iboutlet-is-nil-but-it-is-connected-in-storyboard-swift - View Controller may not have loaded its hierarchy..

Comment: Since you are  instantiating `NoteViewController` with a simple initialiser rather than from a nib/storyboard none of the outlets will be set.