# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem to execute a function in a viewController from other viewController

I have two view controllers one called

```
ubicacionContainerViewController
```

and other

```
ReservaViewController
```

so I want to call a function in the reservaViewController from ubicacionContainerViewController

so in the `ubicacionContainerViewController` I have this code:

```swift
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let reservaViewController: ReservaViewController = 
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReservaViewController") as! 
      ReservaViewController

reservaViewController.cambiarContainer()
```

I used the code above to call a function in ReservaViewController and all is ok it is called

but now in `ReservaViewController` I have theses buttons

```
 @IBOutlet weak var btnSelectUbicacion: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var btnSelectServicio: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var btnSelectHora: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var btnConfirmacionReserva: UIButton!
```

and this function:

```swift
func cambiarContainer() {
    self.btnSelectUbicacion.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
             "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal) // here is the error
    self.btnSelectServicio.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
    self.btnSelectHora.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
            "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
    self.btnConfirmacionReserva.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
             "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
}
```

so the problem is when I press a button in `ubicacionContainerViewController` to call appear that error.

I have tried using the "?"

```swift
func cambiarContainer(posicion: Int) {        
    self.btnSelectUbicacion?.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
             "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal) //no the error disapear
    self.btnSelectServicio?.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)

    self.btnSelectHora?.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
            "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
    self.btnConfirmacionReserva?.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
             "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
}
```

now all is ok it works ok but the problem is that the background image of the buttons does not work . nothing change.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29322364/1226963 - you are calling `cambiarContainer()` too soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: so where can i call the function while ReservaViewController is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you call `cambiarContainer` the outlets are not connected yet and therefore the code crashes.

Delete

```
reservaViewController.cambiarContainer()
```

and move the code to modify the UI into `viewDidLoad`

```
func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad() 
   self.btnSelectUbicacion.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal) // here is the error
   self.btnSelectServicio.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
   self.btnSelectHora.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
   self.btnConfirmacionReserva.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: viewDidLoad what viewController of?

Comment: In `ReservaViewController`

Answer (score -1):

the problem here is that you have already instantiated your **ReservaViewController** but its view have not been loaded yet, and the *cambiarContainer* method its calling one or more of the (currently not loaded) outlets of the controller; that's why it's pointing you that the references are nil.

Try loading the view before calling the *cambiarContainer* method, by adding the following line:

```
_ = reservaViewController.view
```

Comment: This solution is more of a hack. Just call `cambiarContainer()` after calling `present` or `show` or `push`.

Comment: _ =  reservaViewController.view works all ok but nothing change what i want i dont know why, the app is all ok does not crash but the buttons does not change nothing.

Comment: how can i use present, show or push? if my ubicacionContainerViewController
 is a containerView that is in the ReservaViewController , can you understand me?

Comment: dear @maddy i used self.present(reservaViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) but i have the same error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: This is a hacky workaround that doesn't address the underlying problem.  Rather than the current approach, why not configure the buttons from `viewDidLoad` by calling `cambiarContainer()` there?  This way you know your storyboard will be fully instantiated by the time you try to configure.