# Unwrapping an Optional value for a Label

Tags: swift

in this issue i tried to unwrap it by adding ! next verifiedLabel in viewDidLoad to become verifiedLabel!.text but the result is still printing Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Thank you

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    verifiedLabel.text = "" }


 self.verifiedLabel.text = user.isPhoneVerified ? "Verified" : "Not Verified" }
```

[image]

Comment: Is `verifiedLabel` and outlet? Is it connected outlet? If it's not outlet, do you set value to this variable?

Comment: yes verifiedLabel is connected outlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are force unwrapping an optional by adding a `!`, so if the value is null like it is in your case the program will crash.

To unwrap an optional in a safe way (for a generic case) follow this method from Hacking With Swift:

```
var name: String? = nil
if let unwrapped = name {
print("\(unwrapped.count) letters")
} else {
print("Missing name.")
}
```

In your **SPECIFIC** case however `verifiedLabel` is likely your label set on a storyboard. So you can unwrap it like `var verifiedLabel:UILabel!` since the value should NOT be null.

So now since its null, a) please check your outlet connections and if everything looks good b) check this thread for debugging: [IBOutlet is nil, but it is connected in storyboard, Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321383/iboutlet-is-nil-but-it-is-connected-in-storyboard-swift)