# How to embed UIImage to UILabel in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uikit, uilabel

I want to make a UILabel (for a photo tag) with a small x icon in the top right corner, so that when I hit the x, the UILabel disappears.

I found this is one way to embed the image into the ui label:

```
var attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "rsz_cancel30.png")
var attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
var myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelString)
myString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
uiLabel.attributedText = myString`
```

However, when I try to use uiLabel.sizetoFit(), it "sizes to fit" the image, so the label becomes the size of the small square icon, instead of fitting **both the text and the uiimage.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I stupidly had the line

```
uiLabel.text = labelString
```

commented out for whatever reason.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than trying to embed the image into the UILabel, you should create a **UIContainerView** that contains a UILabel and UIImageView. This way, you can use Auto Layout to get auto-sizing to work properly while still being able to create the view programmatically.

You can find an excellent tutorial on [Container Views here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/4967340). To sumarize, try:

1. Drag a Container View to the Storyboard
2. Create a new class for the new UIViewController
3. Put the UILabel and UIImageView inside, auto layout
4. Hook up an ember segue, auto layout