# Why apple does not allow addition of one ViewController into another in Xib, though it is possible programatically

Tags: ios, xib

Any reason why this is not permitted in Xib.

```
-(void)addLeftViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [viewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.leftVw.frame.size.width, self.leftVw.frame.size.height)];
    [self.leftVw addSubview:viewController.view];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: It may be a guard to prevent violating the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that in the storyboard, by using the container view:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @almas for pointing that to me, but while adding that container my Xcode 6.4 crashed and then containerView itself is not coming on my Xcode, any idea how can i get that in future?

Comment: Got the problem. Container View is only applicable to storyboard. I was searching it while I opened Xib.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link helpful

[How to add a subview that has its own UIViewController in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399061/objective-c-how-to-add-a-subview-that-has-its-own-uiviewcontroller/23403979#23403979)