# How to add floating button on top of the UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, floating-action-button, ios9.2

I need to add floating button on top of UITableViewController.

The following link is used for adding  FloatingButton action on top of UIViewController

[Creating a floating menu in an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979342/creating-a-floating-menu-in-an-ios-application)

I already tried to add  this floating button to my UITableViewController but it is not visible.

please help me 
thank you inadvance

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SUITabView

Answer (score 21):

1. First add the UITableView and then the Button. So it should be like this in the XIB Structure (Button is after the Table not before otherwise it will be hidden):

[image: XIB Structure]

2. Set the Button Constraints **related to the Super View** and not related to UITableView.

[image: Button Constraints]

See that button constraints are related to superview. This is important if you want the Floating Button.

If everything is done correctly it would show like this:
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Floating Action button on IOS can be created with way more easier way:

1. Take a button from object library and place it where ever you want it to be placed.
2. Give its height and width 48x48.
3. Connect your button to your class and set its corner raidius to 25

   yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25

There you have your Fab button.