# Insert a floating action button on UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'm trying to add a floating action button (not a floating menu button) which will navigate me to the next view controller with a single click. I'm not getting the floating button right. I have tried the below code and it is not showing the appropriate button on the table view as it is getting scrolled along with the table. Is there any way to stick the button at the same place without getting scrolled along with the table?

```
func floatingButton(){
    let btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 285, y: 485, width: 100, height: 100)
    btn.setTitle("All Defects", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1)
    btn.clipsToBounds = true
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    btn.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    btn.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    btn.addTarget(self,action: #selector(DestinationVC.buttonTapped), for: UIControlEvent.touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(btn)
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073935/how-to-add-floating-button-on-top-of-the-uitableview ? Your button shouldn't scroll with the tableView except if in your code in `view.addSubview(btn)`, `view` is the tableView. Or is your `UIViewController` a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: i already checked that question. Thanks for sharing though. My table view is a xib file..no idea how to set the floating button

Comment: The link you shared tells about the floating menu button..I do not want to achieve floating menu button..instead a single floating action button as shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you currently using tableViewController then no , you must subclass UIViewController add UItableView and your floating button to it

Or you may override scollviewDidScroll and change button y according to tableview current offset

drag scrollview as IBOutlet and set it's delegate to the viewController

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

       let  off = scrollView.contentOffset.y

       btn.frame = CGRect(x: 285, y:   off + 485, width: btn.frame.size.width, height: btn.frame.size.height)
}
```

code snapshot

[image]

in action

[image]
see in action

Comment: why will it not work? isn't a tableViewController a subclass of a UIViewController with a tableView inside? so should tableViewController.tableView.addSubview work?

Comment: Actually the table view is a xib file. So I inserted the above function in the table view class itself

Comment: @josha any content will scroll if not implement scrollviewDidScroll delegate and that inside tableViewController

Comment: you use tableViewController or subclass uiviewcontroller

Comment: I can't use tableviewcontroller as I am using uiscrollview on a view controller and scrolling the scroll view horizontally. I have view controller xibs file on every scroll of scrollview. One of them is a table view onto which I have to add floating button

Comment: yeah...I have taken a normal view controller onto which scrollview lies

Comment: ok..I'll make the necessary changes and if it worked , I'll let you know.

Comment: Where shall I insert the function that you have mentioned?

Comment: in the viewController holding the tableview

Comment: My view controller is holding the scroll view and for the table view, I have created a new class known as DestinationVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163317/discussion-between-saurabh-and-sh-khan).

Comment: implement it in DestinationVC

Comment: What the function does btw?

Answer (score 8):

All subviews added to `UITableView` will automatically scroll with it.

What you can do is **add the button to the application Window**, just remember to remove it when the ViewController disappears.

```
var btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
func floatingButton(){
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 285, y: 485, width: 100, height: 100)
    btn.setTitle("All Defects", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1)
    btn.clipsToBounds = true
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    btn.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    btn.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    btn.addTarget(self,action: #selector(DestinationVC.buttonTapped), for: UIControlEvent.touchUpInside)
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        window.addSubview(btn)
    }
}
```

and in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    btn.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

For iOS 13 and above you can check for the key window using this extension:

```
extension UIWindow {
    static var key: UIWindow? {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where to add the above function

Comment: @Saurabh viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Comment: @ahbou couple of things. On this line `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` is showing this error `'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0` do you know how can I replace that line? to make work your solution for iOS 13?

Comment: On iOS 13, an app can have multiple windows. See this answer for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031897/3698961

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working example on XCode 10 with Swift 4.2.

Note that the FAB button will disappear when the view disappears, and reappears when the controller is loaded again.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

lazy var faButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fabTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupTableView()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let view = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        view.addSubview(faButton)
        setupButton()
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let view = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, faButton.isDescendant(of: view) {
        faButton.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

func setupTableView() {
    tableView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
}

func setupButton() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        faButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -36),
        faButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -36),
        faButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
        faButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
        ])
    faButton.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    faButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    faButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    faButton.layer.borderWidth = 4
}

@objc func fabTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    print("button tapped")
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 64
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 32
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that is worked for me. In my table view controller, defined a button first, then override the function **scrollViewDidScroll()**, like this:

```swift
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let bottomImage = UIImage(named: "yourImage.png")
        let yPst = self.view.frame.size.height - 55 - 20
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 12, y: yPst, width: 55, height: 55)
        button.setImage(bottomImage, for: .normal)
        button.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        button.layer.zPosition = 1
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let off = self.tableView.contentOffset.y
        let yPst = self.view.frame.size.height
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 12, y:off + yPst, width: button.frame.size.width, height: button.frame.size.height)
    }

    @objc private func buttonClicked(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        // do something when you tapped the button
    }
}
```