# Programmatical Floating Button over tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, floating-action-button

I'm trying to create a floating button over `tableViewController`, so far my code looks like this, but the Button sticks between two cells, so it's not floating...

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 550, width: 75, height: 75))
button.backgroundColor = .yellow
button.setTitle("To Jobs", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: You could add the button to the window, so it will be on top of the tableView.

Comment: What do you mean by " Button sticks between two cells, so it's not floating..." ??

Comment: Are you saying that the button moves when the table view is scrolled ?

Comment: Refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298984/insert-a-floating-action-button-on-uitableview-in-swift-4 it might help you some way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because **self.view = UITableView** inside `UITableViewController` , so you need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 550, width: 75, height: 75))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.backgroundColor = .yellow
        button.setTitle("To Jobs", for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        button.frame.origin.y = 550 + scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }

}
```