# Multitasking - Should I go for UICollectionView or UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout, multitasking

My requirement is basically listing some details of an employee.

So, it is a list of 100s of employees.

The app is an iPad landscape application. The screen will look somewhat as follows.

[image]

I was thinking of a UITableView with a custom cell, that contain labels horizontally arranged on it as per my client's requirement.
But on considering the multitasking in iOS 9, I now face an issue in using this as I will not be able to maintain the same layout if the view reduce to 1/3rd or 1/2.

Now the best option I can think of is to use a UICollectionView with the labels shown as rows. That is something as follows:

[image]

I would like to get your suggestions on this and the best practises to be considered on designing a similar layout.

Comment: (1) collection view is far more flexible.  (2) you absolutely have to master autolayout, which will solve most of the problems you describe.  (3) you have to get with [container views](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884) which are the basic way to make stuff in iOS now, and solve the problems you describe.