# Multiple UIViewControllers in a tvOS Storyboard Scene

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard, tvos

I'm trying to create a storyboard scene for tvOS where a `UIViewController` has an embedded `UITableViewController`. I'm unable to make the connection, though, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

At present, I have a `UIViewController` scene, and a separate `UITableViewController` scene. The `UIViewController` scene has a `UITableView` within it. When I try to make an "embed" connection from the `UIViewController` to the `UITableViewController`, I can't select anything else in the Document Outline. I tried adding another `UITableViewController` to the main scene's dock, and it will only let me drop it onto the canvas, not as a part of the main scene.

I haven't done this with iOS yet, so I'm not sure if what I'm trying is supposed to work, and it's a bug I need to report, or if I'm taking the wrong approach.

Comment: In particularly you need to use container views *in code* for this problem. It does work perfectly in tvOS.  there are many long explanations of container views in such situations, including https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a subview that has its own UIViewController in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399061/how-to-add-a-subview-that-has-its-own-uiviewcontroller-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed segues can't be created from a "normal" UIView, you need to set it from a ContainerView class that you need to drop into your UIViewController.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think you're understanding correctly. Right now, I'm not trying to trigger a segue to another scene. I'm trying to embed my table view and controller into another view.

Comment: oops, you are correct. are you sure you are creating the embed segue (this is a segue as well) from the ContainerView and not the UIViewController?

Comment: Argh. I got it now. I didn't realize that "Container View" was an actual type of view you could drop in (since it's at the _bottom_ of the list). Now I get it. If you want to update your answer to reflect that (replacing my UITableView in the UITableViewController scene with a "Container View"), I'll accept it.