# How to manage table view rows inside a single viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, swift-protocols

Let's say I have a tableView which has 20 rows inside containing data(e.g: contact names), and whenever any random row is tapped it shows another table view which contains contact name details , so far I have created 2 table views, one is for "contact name" and one is for "contact details"
(only for one row yet )

but the problem is that If I keep creating ViewControllers for each row details, I will end up having 20 separate Controllers which makes storyBoard massive and messy, So I searched some good techniques to simplify this, but could not find the better approach yet.. .
AnyOne, can suggest some out of their shelf or under the belts..? )

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Instead of 20 separate view controllers, you just need one generic viewcontroller in which you pass data to it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create 20 ViewController, you need exactly 2. The first for the "Contact List" and the Second one for the Details. You simply use the `prepareForSegue` method passing one contact to the Detail ViewController where you then display its Data. You **reuse** the Detail ViewController for every Contact!

Prepare for Segue: [Swift 3 - Prepare Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477752/swift-3-prepare-segue)

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to create separate controller in StoreyBoard for each item.
What you need it's just create one controller and call `performSegueWithIdentifier`  or call:

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdentifier") as! SomeViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
viewController.configure(yourDetails)
```

where `configure(yourDetails)`is your configuration methods, where you passing your details