# Add UITableView in subview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, addsubview

I implemented `UITableView` in subview like :

```
self.view.addSubView(tableView)
```

... with delegate and datasource. All works good, but it doesn't scroll.

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: make sure view accepts interaction. `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` ?

Comment: @Dupont Castoche . Under the table view there is a checkbox that says "Scrolling Enabled".Check if it's true or not.

Comment: Both `userInteractionEnabled` and `scrollEnabled` are set to `true`

Comment: @Dupont Castoche Can you show some more code?

Comment: Make sure there is nothing above table view.

Comment: I tried without `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` and `scrollEnabled` it is scrolling for me, Can you provide more code

Comment: Do you have any other gesture recognizers set up?  There might be something else stealing touches.

Comment: you very likely want to start using container views ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884