# How to cache UIViewControllers for UICollectionViewCell use?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have created a `UICollectionView` with cells containing several types of `UIViewController` views as their contentView. I would like to cache the `UIViewController`'s which are not in use. I have tried creating a dictionary of the currently used `UIViewController`'s based on their indexPath, and a set of unused `UIViewController`'s to to be recycled `UIViewController`'s. Im noticing however that my UIViewControllers are not being deinitialized. I've based my implementation on these answers [Add UIViewController to UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887714/9367155) and [Make PageViewController reuse viewControllers like tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36876103/9367155).

Below is my implementation

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        addViewController(toCell: cell, at: indexPath, of: viewTypes[indexPath.item])
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        removeViewController(fromCell: cell, at: indexPath)
     //   cleanCachedViewControllers(index: indexPath.item)
    }

    func addViewController(toCell cell:UICollectionViewCell, at indexPath:IndexPath,of type:ViewControllerType){
        var childViewController:UIViewController!

        if let cvc = currentViewControllers[indexPath]{
            childViewController = cvc
        }else{
            childViewController = TestViewController()
            currentViewControllers[indexPath] = childViewController
        }
        self.addChild(childViewController)
        childViewController.view.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
        cell.contentView.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        childViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func removeViewController(fromCell cell:UICollectionViewCell, at indexPath:IndexPath){
        guard let childViewController = currentViewControllers[indexPath] else {
            return
        }
        print("remove view controller called")
        childViewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        childViewController.removeFromParent()
    //        currentViewControllers[indexPath] = nil
   //         currentViewControllers.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
        childViewController.view = nil
        recycledViewControllers.insert(childViewController)
    } 

    func getRecycledViewController(type:ViewControllerType)->UIViewController{

        var unusedViewControllers = recycledViewControllers.filter { (viewController) -> Bool in
            return viewController.isKind(of: type.type) && viewController.parent == nil
        }

        if let reusableViewController = unusedViewControllers.first{
            recycledViewControllers.remove(reusableViewController)
            return reusableViewController
        }else{
            let newViewController = type.initializeViewController()
            //            recycledViewControllers.append(newViewController)
            return newViewController
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a circular reference that is keeping your objects from deallocating.

Xcode 8 and higher allows you to debug and visualize the current memory graph. This is very useful to troubleshoot why an object is not being deallocated.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/