# Xcode - How can i programmatically embed/change view controller within a container view?

Tags: xcode, view, swift3, controller, containers

I am trying to programmatically set / or change the embedded **View Controller** inside a **Controller View**.

I have 3 different View Controllers, that I would like to show in the Container View, all depending on if the user is logged in or not.

I have looked around and tried a bunch of code, I found one that worked, but the code changed the self view, and not the view containers view.

A lot of the code I have tried have also not been in Swift 3, so as a new app developer, this has been quite stressful, as I tried to convert it to Swift 3.

Can anyone provide a solution for changing the embedded view controller inside a view container? Thanks.

Comment: fully explained here with up-to-date code:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

Answer (score 24):

I might have found a solution for this. I'm answering here, in case it can help anyone else in my situation.

What I did was add a new **View Controller** and then embed it to the **View Container** - This will work as a "master view" - I then use this blank view controller to decide which other view controller should be changed within the self of the blank.

Here's some code I have in the blank view controller, but I suppose the blank view controller can also be used as a master view controller (in my case for "Account"), and then it can add the login/register view as a child.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateView()
}

private lazy var loginViewController: loginViewController = {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController") as! loginViewController

    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()

private lazy var registerViewController: registerViewController = {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registerViewController") as! registerViewController

    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()

private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Add Child View Controller
    addChildViewController(viewController)

    // Add Child View as Subview
    view.addSubview(viewController.view)

    // Configure Child View
    viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    // Remove Child View From Superview
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}

private func updateView() {

    add(asChildViewController: registerViewController)

    /*
     if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
     remove(asChildViewController: sessionsViewController)
     add(asChildViewController: summaryViewController)
     } else {
     remove(asChildViewController: summaryViewController)
     add(asChildViewController: sessionsViewController)
     }
     */
}
```

Credit to this guy: https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Comment: Brilliant, easy to implement, doesn't overload device and works fine on different devices!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, works great! Coming from Android development, this is the equivalent of swapping fragments inside a frame. Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do that is to have 3 container views in Storyboard above each other, each one of them is connected to a different view controller, then in your code, make 2 of these 3 container views hidden and leave one visible based on your business needs.

This is described in detail in [this blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/). Hope this helps!

Comment: This one is much simpler

Comment: Doesn't seem to me as the right way to do that as all of the three view controllers would be existing side by side and not only for the time you actually need them.