# Navigate to viewController when programmatically created button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a framework module using swift. Need to pop up an alert or ViewController when the button tapped.
Buttons are creating programmatically. Currently button is displaying, but actions are not working. Below is the code.
In Framework class

```
public class CreateAdminMenu {

    let alertVC = AlertView()

    public init() {

    }

    public func createMenuItem(itemTitle: String) -> UIButton{
        let menuItem = UIButton(type: .system)
        menuItem.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 150, height: 100)
        menuItem.backgroundColor = .blue
        menuItem.setTitle(itemTitle, for: .normal)
        menuItem.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuItem_touchUpInside(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
        return menuItem
    }

    @IBAction func menuItem_touchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Menu Item tapped")
        alertVC.showAlert()
    }
}

class AlertView: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //self.showAlert()
    }

    func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test Item", message: "button tapped", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

In App, ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let menu = CreateAdminMenu()
        let item = menu.createMenuItem(itemTitle: "Test Item 1")
        view.addSubview(item)
    }
}
```

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First and foremost, you should definitely not add the `IBAction` in framework.

#### Two issues

1. You just initialize `AlertView` without add/embedding it in `ViewController`.
2. You are presenting the `UIAlertController` in another view.

```
       public class CreateAdminMenu {

            public init() {

            }

            public func createMenuItem(itemTitle: String) -> UIButton {
                let menuItem = UIButton(type: .system)
                menuItem.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 150, height: 100)
                menuItem.backgroundColor = .blue
                menuItem.setTitle(itemTitle, for: .normal)
                return menuItem
            }
        }

        class AlertView  {
            func showAlert() -> UIAlertController {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test Item", message: "button tapped", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                return alert
            }
        }


        class ViewController: UIViewController {

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

                let menu = CreateAdminMenu()
                let item = menu.createMenuItem(itemTitle: "Test Item 1")
                item.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuItem_touchUpInside(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
                view.addSubview(item)
            }

            @IBAction func menuItem_touchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
                    let alert = AlertView()
                self.present(alert.showAlert(), animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Comment: And in addition to this answer, if you want to see which button is tapped, you can set tag to each button and in menuItem_touchUpInside method you can identify the button with the tag.

Comment: @mahan; I was trying not to use UIViewController delegate in CreateAdminMenu class and want to show the VC in Framework. In your solution, IBAction moved to ViewController class which I try to move to framework class

Comment: @mahan, goal is creating a framework (like UIKit, Foundation ...etc) In the question I have mentioned. "In App" means, using created framework

Comment: @mmk You can only present  `UIAlertViewController` in `AlertView ` should you embede `AlertView` in `ViewController`. Honestly, that is a very bad architecture if you do so.

Comment: @mahan; what do mean by embed AlertView? I have build the framework project and embed it to app. After that I can import that framework as "import xxxxx"

Comment: @mmb you should definitely not add `IBAction ` in framework.  See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118016/xcode-how-can-i-programmatically-embed-change-view-controller-within-a-contain

Comment: @mmk if you write the button action in framework but still its target  can be added somewhere elsealso as you  are returning the button reference from createMenuItem(itemTitle: String) method. So it may cause problems.

Comment: @mahan, @Najeeb; Thanks for your answers and advices.