# Is it correct to replace uiviewcontroller view to custom view?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to update my uivewicontroller view hierarchy at runtime.
It is working fine but I am not sure whether is the correct practice or not.

As I can see the root view property of UIViewController is having setter.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view

Below is the code sample:

```
@IBAction func showUserDetailsScreen() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserDetailsVC")
    
    /* The basic idea is to replace "UIViewController root view" to
     "my custom message view" and then adding initial "UIViewController root view" as
     subview to "my custom message view".
     So view hierarchy will be like as follow:
     
     Old: UserDetailsVC >> view
     New: UserDetailsVC >> SecureView >> view
     
     Is it a safe and correct practice to do this?
     */
    
    if let secureView = createSecureView() {
        
        let bgView = UIView()
        bgView.backgroundColor = .blue
        secureView.frame = self.view.bounds
        secureView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        bgView.addSubview(secureView)
        
        let controllerView = controller.view
        
        bgView.frame = controller.view.bounds
        bgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        // Exchanging UserDetailsVC's view to Custom view.
        controller.view = bgView
        
        if let view = controllerView {
            
            view.frame = controller.view.bounds
            view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            
            // Adding initial UserDetailsVC's view as subview to secure view.
            secureView.addSubview(view)
        }
    }
    
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}

private func createSecureView() -> UIView? {
    
    if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SecureView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? SecureView {
        return view
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

As in any existing project, a UIViewContoller can have a very complex view hierarchy. So this is a quick and easy fix to have control over all screens.

Any suggestion or feedback is most welcome.

Comment: As far as I know `UIViewController.view` should be manually set only if you override `loadView()`. Your problem to me seems solvable by using the decorator pattern. I would create a `SecureViewDecoratorController<VC: UIViewController>` that decorates any passed VC with the secure view. You will need to know how to create a container VC (`addChild` APIs) for this to work. There might be other ways of course but I wouldn't continue with what you are doing here.

Comment: As everyone has said you simply use container views here, a concept which is completely built in to iOS and exists for this purpose. Completely forget about what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change `UIViewController.view` outside of `loadView()`. Not sure if it will run normally but either way it's a bad idea as it can cause confusion of what the `view` is.

You should instead have all this `SecureView` hierarchy happening within the `UserDetailsVC`. For example, in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.view.addSubview(self.bgView)
self.bgView.addSubview(self.secureView)
self.secureView.addSubview(self.contentView) // content view could be what you were putting as `UserDetailsVC.view`
```

Or if you need this to be more reusable across the app with different generic view controllers, one easy method (of many) would be having a `SecureViewController` class which other view controllers like `UserDetailsVC` inherit from.

```
class SecureViewController: UIViewController {

    let secureView = SecureView()

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = self.secureView
    }
}

class UserDetailsVC: SecureViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        self.view.addSubview(AnyViewYouWant()) // since self.view refers to secureView, you're adding to the secureView
    
        // This is the same as:
        self.secureView.addSubview(AnyViewYouWant())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply use **container views for this very purpose**.

They have been built-in to iOS / UIKit for 15+? years.

You use container views constantly and always to do everything in iOS.

In storyboard simply click to add a container view ...

[image]

Since it's perhaps the most basic building block of every iOS layout, you can find innumerable tutorials, etc.

Here's a [long detailed one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399061/how-to-add-a-subview-that-has-its-own-uiviewcontroller-in-objective-c/23403979#23403979) which also explains clearly how to do it in code (which is easy) if you prefer.